# What is this type of dribbling called in basketball?

Tags: basketball, terminology

[image]

How do people call it, when you dribble the ball over the defender on one side while yourself passing through the other side?

Comment: Not really sure there is any specific name for it.

Comment: Wrap around pass to himself.

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary street ball move. Could say it was an in-and-out dribble into a wrap around pass to himself. Either way, nice move if you can get away with it!